# Broken web app & modal rendering in Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, display, multiple-monitors, display-adapter

I've noticed that certain web applications do not render correctly on the monitors. This also occurs on local development environment.

Here's an example of what is happening. Here we have the main app page in the background with the modal displaying in the foreground with the broken rendering occurring in both. Mouse-over seems to randomly cause certain elements to appear/disappear (usually the latter).

[image]

This does not occur in Firefox and another computer with the same OS (Ubuntu 16.04) does not have the same issue so I'm not sure exactly what's causing it. This does not occur for all web applications/pages but I don't notice a clear pattern. The dual monitor setup is a bit jury-rigged with multiple adapters on one monitor, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Browser: Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

monitor 1: HDMI to DVI (adapter), DVI to DVI

monitor 2: USB to mini-USB, mini-USB to VGA (adapter), VGA to VGA

I notice when I unplug monitor 2, both screens go black and when I plug it back in I am prompted to log back into Ubuntu so I suspect that second connection is at least partially responsible for the issue.

Could this be a driver issue further complicated by the monitor connections? How can I troubleshoot this?